# Regards to Java programming OO

Tags: java

```
1  public class Student
2  {
3      private String name;
4      private int grade;

5      public Student(String n)
6      {
7          name = n;
8      }

9      public void setGrade(int g)
10     {
11         grade = g;
12     }

13     public boolean hasPassed(Student s)
14     {
15         return (grade > 45);
16     }

17 }
```

I have just started studying Java and I am going through some of the basic questions.
There are several questions I'd like to ask just to make sure I have got the questions right.
Purpose of line 5 - 'Line 5 defines a constructor for the class student'
Function that describes the line 13 to 16 'This code defines a method called hasPassed that determines if a student has passed scc110'

Function of line 3 - This code creates an instance variable of type private
Function of line 9 - This code creates a method that is an example of a mutator method.

I'd like to know whether my answers are correct and if not, would you be able to describe what it does please? This exercise that I am going through has no feedback nor answer so I can't tell whether I got the answers wrong or not.

Comment: Add line numbers or be more specific. Also, things you should go read about: constructors (what are they and how to define them?), accessors and mutators (what are they?), instance variables, access modifiers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a homework checking service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are all correct with one exception: "Function of line 3 - This code creates an instance variable of type private"

Line 3 does not create an instance variable thats type is private, but rather has a visibility of private (only methods contained in the Student class can access it, and other classes must use a public String getName() method. This variable is of type String and has the access specifier is private.

Comment: so basically, this code creates an instance variable of type string instead of instance variable of type private?

Comment: Exactly! The variable type is String, private just means that only methods defined in the Student class can access it. If you tried to access it from a different class like this: String studentName = myStudent.name; you would get an error because its private and only visible to its containing class. You would need to access it with a public method thats within the class because it will have access to it because its a member of the student class.

Comment: I just needed some clarification, thank you.

Comment: And regards to function line 9 - mutator (set) methods. This is because public methods that change the value of a private instance variable, they have no return value (void), they set the value of the variable to the given parameter, they have a single parameter, same type as the instance variable, they are named after the variable they relate to and because they are declared public. I guess, that question was easy enough.

Comment: Not exactly. They're public not because of some kind of relationship with the parameter but because when you want to set the grade by using the mutator method setGrade(grade); you will be doing so from outside of the class so it needs to be public so in your other class, say main, you can use the method. If it was private you could not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Line 5 is a constructor of the class Student. 13 through 16 do define a method hasPassed but I don't know what you mean by scc110. It returns whether or not the integer "grade" is greater than 45 but it has a passed in "Student" s that it doesn't use for anything. A bit strange. Line 3 creates a type String that is private to the class meaning only the class itself has access to it. You are correct regarding line 9 being a mutator method.

Comment: Be more specific about the instance variable. The whole class doesn't have access to it. Only instance methods, constructors, blocks, and fields have access to it.

Comment: What does that leave that does not have access to it? My understanding led me to believe that it was indeed available to the whole class.

Comment: `static` methods, blocks, and fields. They can't access it directly. OP might misunderstand that.

Comment: Oh? I was not aware of that. Guess I learned something new :-)

Comment: Yes, that's one distinction between _instance_ variables and _class_ variables.